# How to persist state of scenes in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have been trying to persist data across scenes in JavaFX.

What I mean by that: when you for e.g write something to textArea in Scene1, then you switch to Scene2 and then you switch back to Scene1, the text you wrote is still there. You also keep the same stage, so you are only switching scenes, and not stages.

Right now I am switching scenes like this:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
            "../scenes/teamScene.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root);
    Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(scene2);
```

But this always loads completely new scene, deleting the data. I am aware that you can pass objects to a scene using the scene's controller, but this is viable when you always pass the same object, e.g current logged in user object. What I want to achieve is persist the **state** of current scene for as long as possible.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you want to preserve `FXMLLoader` mechanism I'd use some kind of serialization/deserialization with data persistance (perhaps simple file would do). Loading values could be done in FXML `initialize` method. In my opinion though simpler solution would be introducing something like `SceneManager` class which is responsible for switching scenes. You can cache scenes there, perhaps in form of `Map<View,Scene>`  where `View` is some type (maybe enum?) describing what you want to show. All depends on complexity of your program.

Comment: @michelson So if I wanted to use the SceneManager class, could it be implemented as Singleton so the garbage collector does not delete this object and then keep instances of all the scenes in the Map variable? Other classes could just call this singleton to give them scene that they want. If the scene object is null, initialize it and then return it. Would it work, in theory?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of `SceneManager` as singleton. And everything else exactly as you wrote. In fact I was doing scene changing like that before I switched to SpringBoot plus FXWeaver - you might want to check them out.

Comment: Use an MVC approach and share a single model with all the controllers. Then just initialise the state of each scene from the model. Also, do you really need to reload the FXML every time? Why not load each FXML once and then just reshow the required one each time?